# angularjs : Why does the filter not work?

Tags: angularjs

Please help fix the script.

html:

```
            <li ng-repeat="date in dateArr | dateFormatter}">
                <span class="date">{{date}}</span>
            </li>
```

js:

```
angular.module('App', [])
    .controller('lsController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.dateArr = [
            '10.10.2016',
            '11.10.2016',
            '12.10.2016',
            '13.10.2016',
            '14.10.2016',
            '15.10.2016'
        ];   

        /*$scope.dateFormatter = function(date) {
            return date.slice(0, 6);               
        }*/     
    })
    .filter('dateFormatter', function (date) {
        return date.slice(0, 6); 
    });
```

I use angular 1.4.8

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/509jepey/1/)

I need use filter, which cut the datestring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter is not constructed properly.

A filter needs to return a function that contains the arguments for the filtering and returns the result

```
.filter('dateFormatter', function () {
      return function(dateString){
         return dateString.slice(0, 6); 
      }
});
```

Then you have this set to filter in the ng-repeat but putting it there it would need to return a filtered array, not a string input and manipulation. So it needs to be placed where you pass in a string

```
<li ng-repeat="date in dateArr">
        <span class="date">{{date | dateFormatter}}</span>
</li>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8w0qg31x/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Your filter is wrong. Check de filter [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) for more details

```
.filter('dateFormatter', function () {
    return function(date){
        return date.slice(0, 6)
    } 
});
```

Also the way you use your filter is wrong. Take it out of `ng-repeat`

```
<span class="date">{{date | dateFormatter }}</span>
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/daguru/509jepey/14/)